# document term matrix using list of terms

Tags: r, text, nlp, mining

I am trying to build a document term matrix using preidentifed terms.  The corpus is identified in the variable cname and the file with the preidentified terms are read into the terms variable which is then converted into a list. When I run the code below I get an empty DTM. The code I am using below.  Any ideas on what I did wrong? Thank you!!!

tom

```
library(tm) 
library(Rmpfr) 
library(stm)

#Loading Documents
cname <- file.path("", "corpus", "goodsmoklss")
library(tm)
corp <- VCorpus(DirSource(cname))

#Transformations
docs<-tm_map(corp,tolower) #AllLowerCase
docs<-tm_map(corp,removeNumbers) #RemoveNumbers

#Remove Stopwords like is, was, the etc
docs<-tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#make Sure it is a PLainTextDocument
documents<-tm_map(docs,PlainTextDocument)


#read in list of preidentified terms
terms=read.delim("C:/corpus/TermList.csv", header=F, stringsAsFactor=F)
tokenizing.phrases <- c(terms)

library("RWeka")

phraseTokenizer <- function(x) {
  require(stringr)

  x <- as.character(x) # extract the plain text from TextDocument object
  x <- str_trim(x)
  if (is.na(x)) return("")

  phrase.hits <- str_detect(x, coll(tokenizing.phrases))


  if (any(phrase.hits)) {
    # only split once on the first hit, so we don't have to worry about    #multiple occurences of the same phrase
    split.phrase <- tokenizing.phrases[which(phrase.hits)[1]] 
    #warning(paste("split phrase:", split.phrase))
    temp <- unlist(str_split(x, coll(split.phrase), 2))
    out <- c(phraseTokenizer(temp[1]), split.phrase, phraseTokenizer(temp[2])) 
  } else {
    #out <- MC_tokenizer(x)
    out <- " "
  }

  # get rid of any extraneous empty strings, which can happen if a phrase occurs just before a punctuation
  out[out != ""]
}

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(documents, control = list(tokenize = phraseTokenizer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with TM, but in the quanteda package you can simply subset or filter.  Here the same principle should apply. I think you should be able to build the DTM and then simply filter based on the vector of terms that your interested in. First make your DTM as above.

```
v <- ("your","terms","here")
to_filter <- colnames(dtm)

#then you can simply filter based on the vector
dtm2 <- dtm[,to_filter %in% v]
```

You might want to consider stemming both your dictionary and your corpus first. If the corpus has a lot of terms and documents memory could be an issue.

Comment: If you don't mind, please accept the answer! Thanks. And happy to help.  You should check out the quanteda package if you do a lot of NLP stuff.